# Webmin administrative panel options are missing

Tags: sudo, webmin

- When I log into Webmin, with the Ubuntu administrative user `frank`, I cannot see most of the administrative options:

[image: Where O' where has my little option gone?]

- `frank` is shown as the `Administration username` in Webmin.
- I accidentally removed the `frank` user from the `sudo` group, last week.
- My VSP provider added the `frank` account back to the sudo group.

  ```
  # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
  %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
  ```

It appears that Webmin is not recognizing that `frank` is back in the `sudo` group.

How do I get Webmin to show all the administrative options for `frank`?

Comment: Have you consulted the Webmin support team, the Webmin documentation, or your provider? We generally do not offer support for "my web control panel isn't working correctly" -- particularly when there is a service provider involved already, or we're talking about a paid product like Webmin (they software vendor or your provider should be your first line of support). If I had to take a guess, Webmin is expecting `frank` to be a member of a specific unix group (besides `sudo`, and he may not be. That's just a wild guess, and I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the guess. I eventually fixed it as described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Webmin handles its own users from within the application itself, meaning, just because a user is a sudoer, doesnt mean it has access to all of the webmin modules.

I had to have my ISP adjust the webmin.acl, in the /etc/webmin folder, that controls the users modules and such. They  duplicated root's settings for my user.